# Display toggle in Chart: XY widget Workshop

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have line chart with multiple layers in Workshop's Chart:XY widget. I would like to add buttons that will allow the end users to toggle on/off some of the lines and have more control over what they would like to compare.

I have tried to use the button group widget, but don't quite understand how to connect it with the chart widget.
How can I add a button to toggle layers in Chart:XY?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you add a legend to a chart (which you can do in the chart config panel), it gives you the ability to toggle the visibility of different series. Would that work for your use case?

[Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C46iM.jpg)

Comment: thanks for the answer! That's how I'm currently handling it. Ultimately, would like to have a toggle button that adds or removes layers. The issue is that the 'XY Chart' graphs require some sort of aggregation on y-axis, rather than exact values. When the filter is removed, we end up with averaged or a summed up values that throws off end users with unexpected graphs. So I thought the toggle will allow the users to control what they want to look further into.